SpringBoot 3 with Spring Security 6 with Custom Filter and Custom Authentication Provider
We have recently migrated our application to SpringBoot 3.3.x with java 21. As part of this migration, we are facing some issue in making our security policies works as
I am giving outline of what we had in security concept, in SpringBoot Security 5.x version

We have SecurityConfig class which was extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (now not extending this any more in Spring Securuty 6.x)

We have entity class which implements Authentication

We have custom filter class which uses this authentication object and after the checks sets the SecurityContext with auth object


public class customFilterClassName implements Filter {
       //...
       doFilter(...){
                  Authentication auth  = user;
                  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                  filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
}


Then we have a AuthenticationProvider class which checks our custom rules and authenticate the users

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProviderClass implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws   AuthenticationException {
        //...
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated(User user, String password){
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bcryptPasswordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword());
    }

}


Inside SecurityConfig , filter class is called inside addFilterBefore and authentication provider class is set in configure method Overirided Below given is SecurityConfig class

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("***").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("**").authenticated()
        ).addFilterBefore(new CustomFilterClassName(param1,param2,param3), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

      //Authentication provider class is set as below
      @Override
      public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       
   auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProviderClass);
      }
}

Issue
Now application is coming up with the latest upgrade and non secured end points are working as expected, but for secured end points, control is not going to our AuthenticationProvider class and no checks done there. We are not sure how this scenario with custom filters and custom authenticationProvider can be implemented with SpringSecurity 6
We tried changing the security class as per new implementation keeping the custom filter and custom AuthenticationProvider the same
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers(".../*").authenticated()
            .requestMatchers(".../*").authenticated()
            .requestMatchers(".../**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
       .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilterClassName(param1,param2,param3), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(datalakeAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}


You have to return authManager after building it so it can be put into spring context like this :
@Bean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) {
    return builder.
            authenticationProvider(authProvider).build();
}


The above didnt work, infact its throwing 403 forbidden right after completing the filter class we called., Any insight to this?

Set Logging level to Debug and than paste error message
